# How to get CPU frequency in c#

Tags: c#, cpu, frequency

How can I get in c# the CPU frequency (example : 2Ghz) ?
It's simple but I don't find it in the environnement variables.
Thanks :)

Comment: Which frequency do you mean? The current one, or the maximum?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
 var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
            "select MaxClockSpeed from Win32_Processor");
 foreach (var item in searcher.Get())
 {
      var clockSpeed = (uint)item["MaxClockSpeed"];
 }
```

if you wish to get other fields look at class [Win32_processor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394373%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: You were expecting it to be in Ghz?

Comment: seems to return in MHz MaxClockSpeed
Data type: uint32
Access type: Read-only
Qualifiers: Units (MegaHertz)

Comment: I did this to convert it, `var clockSpeed = 0.001f * (uint)item["MaxClockSpeed"];`

Comment: MaxClockSpeed does not correctly report a CPU's real maximum clock speed. Likewise, CurrentClockSpeed does not correctly report a CPU's real current clock speed.

Answer (score 5):

Try this code

```
using System.Management;

uint currentsp , Maxsp;
public void CPUSpeed()
{
   using(ManagementObject Mo = new ManagementObject("Win32_Processor.DeviceID='CPU0'"))
   {
       currentsp = (uint)(Mo["CurrentClockSpeed"]);
       Maxsp = (uint)(Mo["MaxClockSpeed"]);
   }
}
```

Comment: `CurrentClockSpeed` sounds like the current one, not the maximum :)

Comment: you should use a dispose statement. using(ManagementObject Mo = new ManagementObject("Win32_Processor.DeviceID='CPU0'")) { ... }

Comment: @Matten just replace CurrentClockSpeed by MaxClockSpeed and you are done

Comment: @Chaker Nakhli -- ok, then this is the preferable solution

Comment: I do not recommend to use ManagementObject as it is way slow. It takes up to 1 second, while ManagementObjectSearcher does the same in under 100ms.
Microsoft recommends to use ManagementClass instead of ManagementObject as it addresses peroformance issues, though some quries stop working. E.g. "Win32_Processor.DeviceID='CPU0'"

Comment: @sampai I couldn't find any sources for your statement. Can you please provide a source for that? And preferably also example code in a separate answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get the turbo speed, you can make use of the "% Processor Performance" performance counter and multiply it with the WMI "MaxClockSpeed" as follows:

```
private string GetCPUInfo()
{
  PerformanceCounter cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "% Processor Performance", "_Total");
  double cpuValue = cpuCounter.NextValue();

  Thread loop = new Thread(() => InfiniteLoop());
  loop.Start();

  Thread.Sleep(1000);
  cpuValue = cpuCounter.NextValue();
  loop.Abort();

  foreach (ManagementObject obj in new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT *, Name FROM Win32_Processor").Get())
  {
    double maxSpeed = Convert.ToDouble(obj["MaxClockSpeed"]) / 1000;
    double turboSpeed = maxSpeed * cpuValue / 100;
    return string.Format("{0} Running at {1:0.00}Ghz, Turbo Speed: {2:0.00}Ghz",  obj["Name"], maxSpeed, turboSpeed);
  }

  return string.Empty;
}
```

The InfiniteLoop method is simply an integer that gets 1 added and subtracted:

```
private void InfiniteLoop()
{
  int i = 0;

  while (true)
    i = i + 1 - 1;
}
```

The InfiniteLoop method is just added to give the CPU something to do and turbo in the process. The loop is allowed to run for a second before the next value is taken and the loop aborted.

Comment: Thank you - unlike CurrentClockSpeed query this actually gives you the real current processor frequency. I removed infiniteloop because I'm interested in current state, not the max possible frequency

Answer (score 3):

One could take the information out of the registry, but dunno if it works on Windows XP or older (mine is Windows 7).

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/HARDWARE/DESCRIPTION/CentralProcessor/0/ProcessorName
```

reads like

```
Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU    Q6600  @ 2.40GHz
```

for me.

Something like this code could retrieve the information (not tested):

```
RegistryKey processor_name = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree);  


if (processor_name != null)
{
  if (processor_name.GetValue("ProcessorNameString") != null)
  {
    string value = processor_name.GetValue("ProcessorNameString");
    string freq = value.Split('@')[1];
    ...
  }
}
```

(source: [here](http://www.mindstick.com/Blog/176/Displaying%20computer%20system%20information%20using%20C))

Answer (score 2):

You can get it via WMI, but it's quite slow so if you're going to be getting it on more than one occasion I'd suggest you cache it - something like:

```
namespace Helpers
{
    using System.Management;

    public static class HardwareHelpers
    {
        private static uint? maxCpuSpeed = null;
        public static uint MaxCpuSpeed
        {
            get
            {
                return maxCpuSpeed.HasValue ? maxCpuSpeed.Value : (maxCpuSpeed = GetMaxCpuSpeed()).Value;
            }
        }

        private static uint GetMaxCpuSpeed()
        {
            using (var managementObject = new ManagementObject("Win32_Processor.DeviceID='CPU0'"))
            {
                var sp = (uint)(managementObject["MaxClockSpeed"]);

                return sp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```