# My C# code is getting errors

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio

I'm new to C#, I found this script online and tried to apply it on my project but I get errors and have no idea how to fix it... 
The ** ** part is where red curly underlines(errors) makes me so headache. 
I doubt the `using` part is missing something isn't?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace cpuinfo
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static int getMaxCPUFreqMHz()
        {

            int maxFreq = -1;
            try
            {

                **RandomAccessFile** reader = new **RandomAccessFile**("/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state", "r");

                bool done = false;
                while (!done)
                {
                    String line = reader.readLine();
                    if (null == line)
                    {
                        done = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    String[] splits = **line.Split("\\s+")**;
                    **Assert**(splits.Length == 2);
                    int timeInState = **Integer**.parseInt(splits[1]);
                    if (timeInState > 0)
                    {
                        int freq = **Integer**.parseInt(splits[0]) / 1000;
                        if (freq > maxFreq)
                        {
                            maxFreq = freq;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                ex.**printStackTrace**();
            }

            return maxFreq;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the code you found is for C#? Also post the errors. I guess it can't find `RandomAccessFile`, `Assert`, `Integer`, and `printStackTrace`, because it is from Java.

Comment: Where is this code from?

Comment: @ArthurRey http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19810/how-can-i-determine-max-cpu-speed-at-runtime

Comment: Just to add: even if you fix the compilation errors, this won't work. You're attempting to access a linux file (/sys/device/...) from a .NET environment. You can't mix Java and C#, Windows and Linux - you need to think a bit more about what you're trying to achieve. Perhaps you're looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923763/how-to-get-cpu-frequency-in-c-sharp

Comment: @darkfang Why did you think it was C# in the first place? It's full android Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like that you use classes from the Java JDK. In C#, we don't use Assert, Integer or RandomAccessFile

You should rewrite your code. Change Assert to Debug.Assert, or Trace.Assert. Change Integer.parseInt to Convert.ToInt32. And I don't really know what a RandomAccessFile is. I guess you are reading stuff from a file. You should

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader ("/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state") {

                bool done = false;
                while (!done)
                {
                    String line = reader.ReadLine();
                    if (null == line)
                    {
                        done = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    String[] splits = line.Split('\\', 's', '+');
                    Debug.Assert (splits.Length == 2);
                    int timeInState = Convert.ToInt32 (splits[1]);
                    if (timeInState > 0)
                    {
                        int freq = Convert.ToInt32(splits[0]) / 1000;
                        if (freq > maxFreq)
                        {
                            maxFreq = freq;
                        }
                    }
                }
}
```

Just change all the stuff in the `try{}` to the code above and it should be ok.

Also, printStackTrace is not in the .NET Framework. You should use `Console.WriteLine (ex.StackTrace)`.

If you have any more errors please let me know.

Comment: Still get some red curly underlines, it shows `The name 'done/reader' does not exist in the current context`.  **Screenshot** -> http://prntscr.com/7wu04w

Comment: Did you forget to put curly braces for the `using` statement? I can't reproduce the error. @darkfang

Comment: Yes I did put the curly braces! On the line `bool done = false;`, I get 2 errors, 1) **Invalid expression term 'bool'** 2) **Syntax error, ',' expected;**  . @Sweeper

Comment: Try to follow what the error said, change the `;` to `,` I guess because this is super strange. I don't think I can help you now. Try asking someone else.

Comment: Ohh! I see! You forgot to put a closing parenthesis for the `using` statement ^v^  Now all is fixed! Thx btw @Sweeper

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're trying to mix Java and C# here - `Integer.parseInt()` looks suspiciously like Java, but namespace and using are very much C#.

I suggest that may be the root cause of your issues.

Comment: Same with the naming convention etc. It's like a mixture, cuz `.Split(...)` and `.Length` are more like C# where in Java they'd probably be like `.split(...)`, `.getLength()` or `length()`

Comment: @Bauss Since I'm using C#, could it be possible to replace the Java function with C# without making any difference in result to my code?

Comment: @Bauss How am I going to rewrite it? Could you fix it for me? I'd been struggle for days...

Comment: Could you tell me exactly what you want to do, perhaps I can come up with something

Comment: @Bauss Basically it get cpu info from a file on android devices. Here is where I copy the code -> http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19810/how-can-i-determine-max-cpu-speed-at-runtime

Comment: Is it from an app or a plugged device to your computer?

Comment: @Bauss What do you mean from an app?