# How to get current CPU clock speed same as in Task Manager?

Tags: c#, .net

How to get current CPU clock speed the same as in Task Manager? WMI `CurrentClockSpeed` returns the value that is less or equal than `MaxClockSpeed` and not exactly the same as Task Manager's clock speed.

Comment: If you poll fast enough, you'll find that the CPU is either 100% in use or idle.  Task Manager polls on a specific interval, and returns the average during that period.

Comment: @Scott that's another good point... the act of simply polling the value will effect the value.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I was going to edit to say "may" instead of "will".. but I'll let it stand... This hypothetical is regarding Scott's "If you poll fast enough"

Answer (score 2):

It's coming from the PerformanceCounter by importing the System.Diagnostics module. Please refer to the [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/392f50ea-327a-4405-9abd-a26af91b3c67/how-to-get-the-percentage-of-usage-for-a-cpu-multicore-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral) for the code example. Just change the parameter to get the value from "Processor Information", "% Processor Performance" and then calculate the CPU frequency by the equation CPU Frequency = "% Processor Performance" * Processor base Frequency. You could use the Windows build-in application "Performance Monitor"  to check more PerformanceCounter indexes to find what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Because the clock speed changes so frequently, much quicker than Task Manager is updating, you're unlikely to ever get the same value.

Comment: But why WMI clockspeed doesn't get higher than max speed? In TaskManager you can see that in high performance mode it gets higher

Comment: @Spirosi I'm not certain of the reason, but I was able to find this for you to try... https://stackoverflow.com/a/57873417/1048799