# How to detect if CPU support Intel Anti-Theft technology?

Tags: c#, c++, security, cpu, intel

From http://ark.intel.com I can find what processors support it. But how to detect it programmatically?  (C++,C#).

In case of Intel's chipsets, I find out that FVEC2 (feature vector register) is used for detection whether is Anti-Theft enabled or disabled.

Comment: look here: http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=102326 also here http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=69735

Answer (score 1):

There are some scripts that will tell you if your system has supports it:

[Anti-Theft Status tool](https://communities.intel.com/docs/DOC-4463).  This tool reports whether or not the system is capable of running Intel® Anti-theft and whether or not there is a valid MEI driver.  It does NOT output the version of the MEI driver, if installed.  This tool is really only useful if you want to know if there is a valid MEI driver on the system and if the system supports Intel® Anti-Theft.

[SCS Discovery Tool](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/download-the-latest-version-of-intel-amt-setup-and-configuration-service-scs): If you want to do an actual "Discovery" of the system, you want to go download the SCS Discovery Tool.  This tool is often pushed down to systems by Manageability Consoles in order to do a system "Scan."  It reports the following: MEI Driver/version, LMS and UNS versions, ME enabled, a host of information needed for implementing Intel AMT, Intel Anti-Theft status, network configurations and more.  It can write everything to the system's registry or to an XML output file.

You can make the SCS Discovery tool write its output to registers so then you could programmatically check the registers.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a few things that might help.

- [Obtain Clockspeed in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020449/c-how-to-obtain-the-current-clock-speed-of-an-intel-i-series-cpu-when-turboboo)
- From above [CPUID in c#](http://devpinoy.org/blogs/cvega/archive/2006/04/07/2658.aspx)
- From above [Intel doc on cpuid](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/processor-identification-cpuid-instruction-note.html)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the tools listed by ChileAddict, from SCS v9.0 the SCS download package includes another tool called PlatformDiscovery. This tool provide a summary of the Intel capabilities in the platform, including the existence (and version) of Anti-Theft.