# Get the realtime CPU speed in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, cpu-usage

[The existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51332103/c-how-to-find-the-cpus-current-clock-speed) suggests `CurrentClockSpeed`, but in my system, it just returns the same value as `MaxClockSpeed`. The code below prints out the same two values over and over again.

```
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            ManagementObject Mo = new ManagementObject("Win32_Processor.DeviceID='CPU0'");
            while (true)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Max=" + Mo["MaxClockSpeed"] + ", Current=" + Mo["CurrentClockSpeed"]);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            Mo.Dispose(); //return and such later in the code
        });
```

But all other applications like Task Manager, CPU-Z, Hardware Info, etc, show variable clock speed. That is, if I run a process that uses 100% of the CPU, the speed goes up, and if I terminate that process, it goes down. How can I get THAT value?

I mean, for example, the value in the "Speed" section of the screenshot I found in Google Search. Not the "Maximum speed" value that never changes.

[image]

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57873417/1911064) related post?

Comment: @AxelKemper Maybe that is it. It seems to be that `cpuCounter.NextValue()` is returning the percentage of the base clock speed. When I tested it it was changing from about 100 to about 110.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean CPU current usage processes 
use this function in seperate thread :

```
private void get_cpuUsage()
        {
            try
            {
                string processname = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
                var perfCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", processname);

                int coreCount = 0;
                foreach (var item in new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_Processor").Get())
                {
                    coreCount += int.Parse(item["NumberOfCores"].ToString());
                }

                while (true)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    double perfVal = perfCounter.NextValue() / Environment.ProcessorCount;
                    int cpu = (int)Math.Round(perfVal, 0);// / 
                    double cpuvalue = Math.Round(perfVal, 1);
                    Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {

                        cpu_bar.Text = cpuvalue.ToString(); // diaplay current % processes 
                    });
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
messagebox.show(ex.message);

            }
        }
```

Comment: No, not the CPU utilisation, the CPU clock speed. I am not sure why you though so, but if that was because the red arrow on the CPU usage graph, I found this image from Google Image Search, as I had noted, so it was not I who put that red arrow and I am not interested in CPU usage.